# Android Instrumentation Tests: 'Could not find test class' using Espresso and Spoon

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, spoon

I'm running my instrumentation tests using Espresso and Spoon. Here's a useful blog I have followed https://medium.com/android-bits/running-espresso-tests-on-multiple-devices-with-spoon-842a5546e3d7

Everything was OK before the deprecation of `ActivityTestRule`. Right now I have migrated to `ActivityScenarioRule/ActivityScenario`. The issue is that it keeps throwing me the error below.

```
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.runOnMainSync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:450)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:673)
    at mypackage.test.MyActivityTest.validateMainView(MyActivityTest.java:41)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   ...
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find test class!
   Caused by: at mypackage.test.-$$Lambda$MyActivityTest$s-_. 
   AV2ffllNOI7pyo0DUVsTz8G4.perform(lambda)
   Caused by: at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source)
```

The `MyActivityTest.java:41` is where I have the
`activityScenario.onActivity(activity -> Spoon.screenshot(activity, "Display-screen"));`

The HTML reports are created but the tests are failing due to the said error. Has anyone experienced this and has solutions?

Comment: I have this problem now. Were u able to find a way?

Comment: @iori24 I haven't found a good solution yet so opted to just revert the usage of `ActivityScenarioRule` for now. How's it going on your end?

Answer (score 0):

The Spoon has two screenshots methods, use the method which has 4 `parameters(activity, tag, String testClassName, Strig  testMethodName)`
Example:

```
 private final String testClassName = "MainActivityUITest";
 private final String testMethodName = "inputFieldVerification";

activityScenario.onActivity(activity -> Spoon.screenshot(activity, "Display-screen", testClassName, testMethodName));
```